# DOM Manipulation using PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to add an attribute to all the links in my site, and I am doing this trough DOM manipulation using PHP. The code is as follows:

```
$dom_document = filter_dom_load($contenu);
// Récupération des liens dans le $contenu
$liens = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($liens as $lien) {
 //Do something here ^^
}
// Retour de la nouvelle valeur du contenu
$dom_el = filter_dom_serialize($dom_document);

return $dom_el;
```

Everything goes fine but it seems like the layout of the HTML is altered. I find that this creates  tags for no visible reason and I actually suspect that "filter_dom_serialize" is behind this alteration but I was not able to come up with a solution for this.
The output of this code allows me to show the pages but I have this tag /p class="h4" added to the source code of the page. also, the script tags are closed without specific reason.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Care to show us the output?

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php